# FIND_IN_SET question or

Tags: sql, mysql

Anyone could help me with a mysql Question? I have a row with a list of items, eg: `'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'` .. sets of 3 elements.. from 3 to 3.. Now how could i search into this with FIND_IN_SET above '4' and return from what sets it is. In that case, to tell me that is from set 2

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('''4''', REPLACE(`some`, ' ', '')) FROM `x` WHERE `id` = 2
```

with that one .. it return me the position .. but now, i want to return a number of set where 4 is come from

'1','2','3' is one set, '4','5','6' is second and '7','8','9' is last

Comment: I think it's really hard to understand what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your sets always have length 3, you can use integer division on the result of FIND_IN_SET (but remember it is one-based so you need to adjust for that):

```
(x - 1) DIV 3 + 1
```

So your expression becomes:

```
(FIND_IN_SET('''4''', REPLACE(`some`, ' ', '')) - 1) DIV 3 + 1
```

Note that this now returns 1 instead of 0 for elements that are not found. If this is a problem then you can test for this case separately or use this expression instead:

```
(FIND_IN_SET('''4''', REPLACE(`some`, ' ', '')) + 2) DIV 3
```